# Populating an array from a directory list in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, ls

I've been trying to take the output of `ls /Applications/` and put each line into an array, then do a for loop of the array.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls /Applications | grep Adobe > adobeapps
adobearray=( 'cat "adobeapps" ')
for i in "${adobearray[@]}"
do
    codeigottadowith $i
done
exit
```

It doesn't work, and I found that even when I try to just declare a simple array with:

```
declare -a adobearray=(item1 item2 item3); echo $adobearray[1];
```

The output is item1[1].  It takes the first element and makes that the whole array.  Why is this wrong?  What dumb thing am I doing? And is there a better way in bash to send the output of ls to an array?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: BTW, `echo $arrayname` only prints the first element, so `echo $arrayname[1]` is just printing the expansion of `$arrayname`, followed by printing the literal sequence `[1]`; it's not actually expressing to you that the first element "is the whole array" in any meaningful respect.

Comment: `declare -p arrayname`. Works for any other shell variable too.

Answer (score 6):

#### What's the Right Way?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Cause a glob with no results to result in empty output, rather than to evaluate
# back to itself.
shopt -s nullglob

# Expand the glob /Applications/*Adobe* into an array
adobe_array=( /Applications/*Adobe* )

# Trim the prefix /Applications/ from each element of that array
adobe_array=( "${adobe_array[@]#/Applications/}" )

# Iterate over that array
for i in "${adobe_array[@]}"; do
  codeigottadowith "$i"
done
```

#### What was wrong earlier?

- [Parsing `ls` is inherently fault-prone](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The command is designed for its output to be read by humans, not programs, and it doesn't support functionality (such as NUL-delimited output) necessary to resolve the related issues robustly.
- `adobearray=( 'cat "adobeapps" ')` -- this puts the string `cat "adobeapps"` itself into the array as its only element; it doesn't actually run the `cat` command at all. If you **did** want to read from a file into an array, you'd be better off using [`mapfile`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) instead (if targeting bash 4.0 or newer), though reading from a file generated with `ls` is inappropriate in the first place.
- `adobearray=( $(cat "adobeapps") )` -- This is closer, but **also** buggy. If an application name contains a space (and `Adobe Acrobat` and `Adobe Photoshop` all contain spaces), you would have `Adobe` as one entry and `Acrobat` as another. And if you had a program named `* Adobe Foobar *`, then the `*`s would be replaced with names of other files in the current directory where this code was invoked.
- `echo $adobearray[1]` -- in order to index into an array, one needs to use braces to surround the parameter expansion; use `echo "${adobearray[1]}"` to emit the second item in your array (the first is index 0).

Comment: You beat me to it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was very helpful.